# How to open new view from sheet in UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm using UIKit in Swift.

I have a button that opens a sheet:

```
@objc func myButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let myTitle = sender.title(for: .normal) {
        let sheet = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myConfigView") as! myConfigViewController
        sheet.title = myTitle
        self.present(sheet, animated: true)
    }
}
```

There is a label on the sheet that, if I press it, I want a new view to open.
But it's not working.
The sheet code:

```
class myConfigViewController: BaseViewController, UISheetPresentationControllerDelegate {
    
    override var sheetPresentationController: UISheetPresentationController{
        presentationController as! UISheetPresentationController
    }

    
    @IBOutlet weak var TitleUILabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var openUILabel: UILabel!
    
    var title:String = ""
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sheetPresentationController.delegate = self
        sheetPresentationController.selectedDetentIdentifier = .medium
        sheetPresentationController.prefersGrabberVisible = false
        sheetPresentationController.detents = [.medium()]
        
        TitleUILabel.text = title
        
        let tapGesture1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(openNewViewLabelTapped))
        openUILabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        openUILabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture1)     
        
    }
    
    
    @objc func openNewViewLabelTapped() {
        print("Open the new View")
        self.dismiss(animated: false){
            let destViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "isNewView") as! isNewViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destViewController, animated: true)
        } 
    }
}
```

It doesn't show any errors.
Do nothing.

What is the solution?

THANKS!

Comment: Not sure but check this may help 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68198904/uisheetpresentationcontrollerdelegate-method-not-called

Comment: *"I want a new view to open"* ... what does that mean? Do you want to *dismiss* the presented `myConfigViewController` and then push to `isNewViewController`? Or are you trying to push to `isNewViewController` inside the presented `myConfigViewController`?

Comment: @DonMag I want dismiss the presented myConfigViewController and then push to isNewViewController. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you **present** a view controller from a controller that is in a navigation controller, the *presented* controller is NOT in the navigation stack.

So, it **has no** `.navigationController` property, and `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(...)` won't do anything.

There are various ways to do what you want -- here is one approach:

- add a `closure` to your `myConfigViewController` class to tell the *presenting* controller to "dismiss and move on"
- set that closure before you present `myConfigViewController`
- in `func openNewViewLabelTapped()` call that closure
- instantiate and push `isNewViewController` from that closure

So, add this property to `myConfigViewController`:

```
public var dismissAndPush: (() -> ())?
```

change your `openNewViewLabelTapped()` func to:

```
@objc func openNewViewLabelTapped() {
    print("Open the new View")
    if dismissAndPush != nil {
        dismissAndPush?()
    } else {
        self.dismiss(animated: false)
    }
}
```

then, in your controller that presents `myConfigViewController`:

```
@objc func myButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let myTitle = sender.title(for: .normal) {
        if let sheet = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myConfigView") as? myConfigViewController {

            sheet.title = myTitle
            
            // set the closure
            sheet.dismissAndPush = { [weak self] in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                self.dismiss(animated: false)
                if let destViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "isNewView") as? isNewViewController {
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destViewController, animated: true)
                }
            }
            
            self.present(sheet, animated: true)

        }
    }
}
```

Now, `openNewViewLabelTapped()` will call the `closure` ... and that is where dismiss and push will take place.

---

As a side note -- **class** names should start with Uppercase letters, **var / property / func** names should start with lowercase letters.